# Not able to create web using COM after deploying my VB.NET project EXE file

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have developed a VB.NET project which will use the SharePoint client DLL file to create a web site by using the credentials. I have executed the EXE file on another one system which does not have .NET and SharePoint. There I am getting an exception when creating the web.

Comment: Does your app not require .Net?

Comment: no idea.But my exe is working for all the other functionalies like it is getting sub site urls of a site collection and all.Even other site elements updation is happening.only creation is throwing exception.

Comment: OK. Is Self Service Site Creation enabled?

Comment: Don't know. How to enable it? Actually my exe works fine in the SP2013 and .net framework installed environment. I tested it in the different server. but when I tested it in a system which does not have both is giving me exception.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2012/07/27/configuring-self-service-site-creation-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: Also, add the exception to your post

Comment: Thanks robert for the quick response.I am checking ur suggestion. I did not get the detailed exception.I will get it and post it.

Comment: I have turned on the Self Service Site creation and now it is creating the Web.And also it is creating the list.but list field is not get created.

Comment: So your original error is resolved, so post the new one as a new question. We need code to help you further. I will post my comment as an answer for you to accept

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the new server has Self Service Site Creation enabled.

You can follow this guide:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768020.aspx:

1. On the server computer click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools,  and then click Microsoft SharePoint Administrator.
2. On the Server Administration page, click Administration next to the virtual server you want to manage.
3. In the Add-Ins section, click Manage Self-Service Site Creation (SSC).
4. In the Script Directory section, in the Name box, type a name for the directory that will contain the Self-Service Site Creation scripts (the default directory is selfserv).
5. In the Script Settings section, select the type of script you want to use (Read-only SSC Scripts, Customizable SSC scripts, or Fully user-customized scripts).
6. Click Enable